# fade other page with url changing without refreshing site

Tags: php, jquery

I have online store, I want to click button and open popup window or modal, but i want to change url without refresh.

for example.

There are three products

Mobile
PC
Tablet

When I click Mobile (Mobile modal will open and url will be mysite.com/products/mobile
But when I close this and open Tablet, I want url change to mysite.com/products/tablet, but without refreshing or redirecting.

Like this https://vp.ru/
When I clicked service button url changed without redirecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for can be done with almost all modern web browsers. Take a look at the [following article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) for more information on how to change the url without refreshing the page.

You basically need to call the `pushState` function when opening the modal:

```
window.history.pushState(stateObj, "Title", "/mobile");
```

Closing the modal will also need to modify the history to get back to the url without the `mobile` part.